# Show hard drive setup in linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, hardware-raid

I am trying to determine this remote server's hard drive setup including RAID.  A developer who was here before me had set it up and I'm trying to determine the procedure for getting things back online if there was a problem.  The first step in that is knowing how things are setup.

`df -hT` output

```
Filesystem    Type    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ikeyprod-root
              ext3    128G   14G  108G  12% /
tmpfs        tmpfs    7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /lib/init/rw
varrun       tmpfs    7.8G  124K  7.8G   1% /var/run
varlock      tmpfs    7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /var/lock
udev         tmpfs    7.8G  148K  7.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs        tmpfs    7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
lrm          tmpfs    7.8G  2.4M  7.8G   1% /lib/modules/2.6.28-11-server/volatile
/dev/cciss/c0d0p5
              ext2    221M   14M  196M   7% /boot
```

`cat /proc/partitions` output

```
major minor  #blocks  name

 104        0  142253280 cciss/c0d0
 104        1  142006536 cciss/c0d0p1
 104        2          1 cciss/c0d0p2
 104        5     240943 cciss/c0d0p5
 252        0  136183808 dm-0
 252        1    5804032 dm-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of commands that provide disk, partition, and other related info (like LVM):

- `cat /etc/fstab`
- `cat /etc/mtab`
- `cat /proc/mdstat`
- `cat /proc/partitions`
- `cat /proc/scsi/scsi`
- `df`
- `fdisk -l`
- `mdadm --examine --scan`
- `dmraid -r`
- `dmraid -b`
- `pvs`
- `vgs`
- `lvs`

I have made this a wiki, so please feel free to add more to the list. Also, some explanation for each of the commands might be nice.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be running a HP smart array. Might be a hardware raid. Check the hardware setup with `cat /proc/driver/cciss/cciss0`. http://cciss.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following commands:

```
$ df -hT
$ cat /proc/mdstat
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdx
```

The first command shows the partitions and their size, fs type, and usage.

The second one shows the Raid status.

The third one lists the partitions of the device /dev/sdx (replace x with a letter such as `a`, `b`, etc.).

Comment: Does this mean I have 2 partitions?  1 ext3 and 1 ext2?

Comment: @Webnet: Yes / fs is ext3 and /boot fs is ext2. You can also see the size, used, and available.